# Missing Files in ARToolKit

Tags: visual-studio-2013, artoolkit

I am working with ARToolKit 5.3.3 trying to build from source. I am getting the following errors when building the simpleOSG example application:

```
error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'DSVL.h': No such file or 
directory
error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'GL/glext.h': No such file or 
directory
error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'GL/glut.h': No such file or 
directory
error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'jpeglib.h': No such file or 
directory
error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'osg/Config': No such file or 
directory
error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'pthread.h': No such file or 
directory
error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'qedit.h': No such file or 
directory
```

The clone from Github is placed on C:/. I have no idea why these files are missing, when building from source on my Mac I have no issues with this. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

ARToolKit 5.3.3, Windows 10, Visual Studio 2013

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Third-party dependencies are not kept in the ARToolKit GitHub repository. To satisfy the missing dependencies you listed, you will need DSVideoLib, GLUT, libjpeg, OpenSceneGraph, pthreads-win32, and the DirectShow SDK.

The easiest way to obtain these is to copy them directly from one of the packaged binary ARToolKit SDKs.

Otherwise, you have a bit of work to do to download and build each dependency.